# How to kill process in iOS programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, process

How to kill/close application/process by PID or name?

I tried to use C function but it doesn't work. (E.g. try to kill LinkedIn application/process).

```
pid_t pid = 3696; //GetProcessPIDForLinkedIn();
kill(pid, SIGQUIT);
```

I don't plan to deploy it on App Store but it should work for non jailbroken devices

Comment: I don't think you can do this without being root.

Comment: exit(0); may be what you want.

Comment: @rptwsthi I think it is about killing a process from exterior, not ending it with `exit(0)`. Only the process itself can call `exit(0)`.

Comment: Yes. I need to kill another process/application (NOT mine)

Comment: @Sergio On Unix-based systems you'll need to be root, I suppose, won't work without. Why would you want it anyway?

Comment: Display a list of apps to see how much memory it takes and close it using my app if necessary. Or doen't run some process after device reboot. But again it should work for non jailbroken devices.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to manually kill processes in order to free up memory. iOS manages it itself, as soon as your app needs more memory iOS will close apps running/sleeping in the background.

Comment: I don't need to keep app/process in task bar/processes list as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are root and on a jailbroken device, you cannot kill other apps programmatically. Apps live in a sandbox and are unable to affect other apps or their documents or data. THe only exception is launching an app and passing data to it. If all these apps are your own then  you could use this as by passing them some data. Otherwise, no.